# Erro ao requisitar dados da minha API com React Access to fetch at from origin CORS policy

Tags: javascript, node.js, react, api, restful

**Eu criei uma API para estudar o consumo e etc, porém na hora de requisitar está me retornando esse erro:**

Access to fetch at 'https://galaxies-api.herokuapp.com/galaxies' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
App.js:42          GET https://galaxies-api.herokuapp.com/galaxies net::ERR_FAILED 200

Código da API:

```html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const galaxies = require('./src/galaxies/galaxies.json');

app.get('/galaxies', (req, res) => {
  return res.json(galaxies);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Servidor online com sucesso!")
});
```

Ela está hospedada no Heroku

Código da aplicação para requisitar a API:

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import './reset.css';

function App() {
  const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
  `;

  const Header = styled.header`
    height: 6vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #25254c;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    h1 {
      cursor: pointer;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
  `;
  const Section = styled.section`
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    img {
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
    }
  `;

useEffect(() => {
  let url = "https://galaxies-api.herokuapp.com/galaxies";
  fetch(url)
    .then((resultado) => resultado.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
    });
}, []);


  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <h1>Galáxias</h1>
      </Header>
      <Section>
        ...
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Gif do erro que está me acontecendo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlZTY.gif)

Comment: Você vai precisar configurar o CORS na sua API. Veja este exemplo https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-cors-in-nodejs-with-express/

Answer (score 0):

## É neccesário configurar o CORS Middleware na API

Por padrão, o Express bloqueia requisições vindas de outros domínios (Cross Origin). Usando a lib `cors` você deve definir os domínios que podem fazer requisições à sua API.

### Instalação

Na sua API, instale a lib com `npm install cors --save`. o Middleware deve ser configurado seguindo o exemplo abaixo:

```js
// Outros imports

const cors = require('cors');
// Seus domínios permitidos devem estar aqui
const allowedOrigins = ['http://localhost:3000']; 
const corsOption = {
    origin: allowedOrigins,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// Suas rotas
```

A partir daí, as requisições vindas de `http://localhost:3000` não serão mais bloqueadas.

### Recursos complementares

- [Cors Middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)